# How to do a multiple select from same column as one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql database table named ***as_items*** as below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| itemid  | item_type | item_number | item_title  | item_content      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 1         |  2          | First Item  | The first item    |
| 2       | 2         |  3          | Second Item | The second item   |
| 3       | 3         |  5          | Third Item  | The third item    |
| 4       | 3         |  1          | Forth Item  | The forth item    |
| 5       | 2         |  4          | Fifth Item  | The fifth item    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get multiple queries from the same column which in this case is "**item_type**" using my php script. In my php script the reference value could one or multiple based on the existence of the character "," in it which my code check for.

```
   if (strpos($itemtypes, ',') !== false) {
        $items = explode(',',$itemtypes);
        $query = "SELECT ";
        foreach ($items as $item){
            $query .= "(SELECT * FROM as_items WHERE item_type=$item ORDER BY item_number ASC) AS j$item, ";
        }
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        $songbook = $songbookids;       
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM as_items WHERE item_type= $itemtypes ORDER BY item_number ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Take into account the query is based on the php final output. When i use the multiple query I get an error from the server as "Operand should contain 1 column(s) "

NOTE:
**Please note the reference item is from my other code where when 2 or 3 item types are selected its output is like "itemtype,itemtype,itemtype" but when only one is selected it is just plain as "itemtype".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the query(s) like that, try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM as_items WHERE item_type IN ('".str_replace(',', '\',\'', $itemtypes)."') ORDER BY item_number ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

This should replace your whole thing, no need to check if `,` is in the string.

Comment: No sir I disagree, dont ignore my check of a comma. please review my question I have added more information to it otherwise I will have to downvote your answer.

Comment: I maintain my answer. Whether there is one or more values, it will have the same behaviour. I have edited my response to include quotes around values though, which is something I forgot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my query I opted to use $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); because I use boolean statements a lot in my code to and it works. Am sorry for being blind to your answer at first. Your comment now has enlighted me alot